# jQuery Mobile listview detail page data chaging only works the first time

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Could someone help? Please run the following code on your browser and see what is happening.

My problem happens whenever a list of products are entered into the listview with display order. For example, the user enter prod1 and display order 1 and then enter prod2 and display order 2. This will add 2 listview items in the listview page. From the beginning the user might want prod1 the display order 1 and prod2 the display order 2. Later the use might change the mind and want to change the prod2 to the display order 2 and the prod1 to the display order 1 so that in some other page prod2 display before prod1. That is the reason a dynamically created detail page is shown when the user clicks one of the listview items in the listview page. In this detail view page the user can change the number and click change
button.

If you enter prod1 1 and prod2 2 into the listview.
Go to detail page prod2 and change to 4, this first time the program works.
However if you go to detail page prod1 and change to 3, the change function couldn't get values 3 to update instead it gets values 4 again.

How can I fix this?

I will post the code piece by piece using the edit mode of this web site so that you can run the code.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BeiHua_Xie1/e5y36otm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are appending the same `details` page into DOM whenever you navigate to change product's display. The below line will return the first value you have entered, it will refer to first `details` page dynamically injected.

```
var fd2 = $.trim($('.ui-page ui-page-theme-a ui-page-active, #doProduct2').val());
```

Even if you inject a new page and navigate to it, you will retrieve the value of `#doProduct2` in first dynamic page.

Your solution is to keep only one `details` page in DOM by removing previous ones.

```
/* remove old page */
$("#details").remove();

/* inject new updated one */
newPage.html(function (index, old) {
    return old.replace(/ID/g, title).replace(/TITLE/g, title).replace(/ORDER/g, order);
}).appendTo($.mobile.pageContainer);

/* navigate to page */
$.mobile.changePage(newPage);
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/sa2eL2j6/)**

Comment: Hello Omar, thank you very much. Your answer is correct. It solved the problem i have been struggling for several days. Thanks again. I don't know how to mark this question as answered.

Comment: @BeiHuaXie I'm glad you got your problem solved. You can tick "correct" mark to left side of my answer.

Comment: I don't understand why it requires 15 reputation which i don't have to vote up.

Comment: @BeiHuaXie your question is marked as an answered now. 15 rep is required to upvote a post. You earn rep by proper participation to the community :)